# Debugging Native C++ from C# project peformance

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, native, dllimport

I have a C# project that references a C++ dll and invokes methods from it using [DllImport()].

When I want to debug/step through the code in the C++ dll, I go to the C# project settings/properties and switch on :

Debug -> Enable native code debugging.

That all works fine, however it can be really really slow. I suspect because it is enabling native code debugging for every c++ dll my project might *indirectly* reference? I was wondering if there was a way to enable native code debugging for only a specific dll? such that performance is generally better, and only is slow when invoking code for the specific dll I have chosen?

I am using VS2017/19

Comment: Enabling debugging shouldn't effect performance, unless you are switching to "debug" builds, or have conditional breakpoints.... That said, there is a "just my code" option for debugging as well.

Comment: I am running a debug build of the C# project with a debug build of the C++ dll.

Comment: Debug builds of C++ are extraordinarily slow in VS; because it does a ton of different checks, and does not optimize your code at all. That being said, it should not make a difference if you're debugging it or not, the code being run is the same. Unless its linking against a Release dll when debugging is off, but I can't see that happening.

Comment: Thats kind of the point. My C++ dll is tiny, yet when I set Debug -> Enable native code debugging, I seem to be enabling native debugging for everything, hence why I think it's so slow. So I was asking if there was a way to enable native debugging only on my dll.

Comment: Debugging in VS will not slow down the code, unless you have  conditional breakpoints. Again though, there is an option, in the debugging options settings, to enable "just my code"

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. It does make the app MUCH slower. If I have native debugging off, then using something like OpenFileDialog is fine. If I have enable native debugging on, then it takes 5s or so for OpenFileDialog to even open it's dialog. And I have "Just my code" enabled

Comment: @wforl Such slowness is not normal behavior. If you look at the Output window when starting to debug, and see (many) failed attempts to load PDB symbol files, maybe doublecheck  the settings under Tools / Options / Debugging / Symbols. You'll also find an option there to load symbols only for some modules.